# HackerRank Climbing the Leaderboard

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This question has to do with [this challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem) on HackerRank. It seems to be failing some cases, but I'm not clear what's wrong with the algorithm (many people seem to have problem with timeouts, that's not an issue here, everything runs plenty fast, and all the cases that are visible to me pass, so I don't have a specific case that's failing).

The essential outline of how the algorithm works is as follows:
First be sure that Alice isn't already winning over the existing highest score (degenerate case), if she is just tell the world she's #1 from start to finish. Otherwise, at least one score on the leaderboard beats Alice's first try.

- Start by walking down the scores list from the highest until we find a place where Alice fits in and record the scores that beat Alice's initial score along the way.
- If we reach the end of the scores list before finding a place for Alice's bottom score, pretend there is a score at the bottom of the list which matches Alice's first score (this is just convenient for the main loop and reduces the problem to one where Alice's first score is on the list somewhere)

At this point we have a (sorted) array of scores with their associated ranks, rankAry[r - 1] is the minimum score needed for Alice to attain rank r as of the end of the if clause following the first while loop.

From there, the main algorithm takes over where we walk through Alice's scores and note her rank as we go by comparing against the benchmarks from the scores array that we setup as rankAry earlier. curRank is our candidate rank at each stage which we've definitely achieved by the time this loop starts (by construction).

- If we're at rank 1 we will be forever more, so just populate the current rank as 1 and move on.
- If we're currently tied with or beating the current benchmark and that's not the end of the line, keep peeking at the next one and if we're also beating that next one, decrease the current benchmark location and iterate
- Once this terminates, we've found the one we're going to supplant and we cannot supplant anything further, so assign this rank to this score and repeat until done

As far as I can tell this handles all cases correctly, even if Alice has repeated values or increases between the benchmarks from scores, we should stay at the same rank until we hit the new benchmarks, but the site feedback indicates there must be a bug somewhere.

All the other approaches I've been able to find seem to be some variation on doing a binary search to find the score each time, but I prefer not having to constantly search each time and just use the auxiliary space, so I'm a little stumped on what could be off.

```
static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice) {
        int[] res = new int[alice.Length];
        if (scores.Length == 0 || alice[0] >= scores[0]) { //degenerate cases
            for (int i = 0; i < alice.Length; ++i) {
                res[i] = 1;
            }
            return res;
        }
        int[] rankAry = new int[scores.Length + 1];
        rankAry[0] = scores[0]; //top score rank
        int curPos = 1; //start at the front and move down
        int curRank = 1; //initialize
        //initialize from the front. This way we can figure out ranks as we go
        while (curPos < scores.Length && scores[curPos] > alice[0]) {
            if (scores[curPos] < scores[curPos-1]) {
                rankAry[curRank] = scores[curPos]; //update the rank break point
                curRank++; //moved down in rank
            }
            curPos++; //move down the array
        }
        if (curPos == scores.Length) { //smallest score still bigger than Alice's first
            rankAry[curRank] = alice[0]; //pretend there was a virtual value at the end
            curRank++; //give rank Alice will have for first score when we get there
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < alice.Length; ++i) {
                if (curRank == 1) { //if we're at the top, we're going to stay there
                    res[i] = 1;
                    continue;
                }

                //Non-degenerate cases
                while (alice[i] >= rankAry[curRank - 1]) {
                        if (curRank == 1 || alice[i] < rankAry[curRank - 2]) {
                            break;
                        }

                        curRank--;
                    }
                res[i] = curRank;
            }

        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of bugs in your algorithm.

### Wrong mapping

Your `rankAry` must map a rank (your index) to a score. However, with this line  `rankAry[0] = scores[0];`, the highest score is mapped to `0`, but the highest possible rank is `1` and not `0`. So, change that to:

```
rankAry[1] = scores[0];
```

### Wrong initial rank

For some reason, your `curRank` is set to `1` as below:

```
int curRank = 1; //initialize
```

However, it's wrong since your `alice[0]` is less than `scores[0]` because of the following block running at the beginning of your method:

```
if (scores.Length == 0 || alice[0] >= scores[0]) { //degenerate cases
    for (int i = 0; i < alice.Length; ++i) {
        res[i] = 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

So, at best your `curRank` is `2`. Hence, change it to:

```
int curRank = 2;
```

Then, you can also remove `curRank++` as your `curRank` has a correct initial value from:

```
if (curPos == scores.Length) { //smallest score still bigger than Alice's first
    rankAry[curRank] = alice[0]; //pretend there was a virtual value at the end
    curRank++; // it's not longer needed so remove it
}
```

### Improve "Non-degenerate cases" handling

Your `break` condition should consider `rankAry` at `curRank - 1` and not `curRank - 2` as it's enough to check the adjacent rank value. Also, a value at `curRank - 2` will produce wrong results for some input but I won't explain for which cases specifically - I'll leave it up to you to find out.

### Fixed Code

So, I fixed your method according to my comment above and it passed it all the tests. Here it is.

```
static int[] climbingLeaderboard(int[] scores, int[] alice) {
    int[] res = new int[alice.Length];
    if (scores.Length == 0 || alice[0] >= scores[0]) { //degenerate cases
        for (int i = 0; i < alice.Length; ++i) {
            res[i] = 1;
        }
        return res;
    }
    int[] rankAry = new int[scores.Length + 1];
    rankAry[1] = scores[0]; //top score rank
    int curPos = 1; //start at the front and move down
    int curRank = 2; //initialize
    //initialize from the front. This way we can figure out ranks as we go
    while (curPos < scores.Length && scores[curPos] > alice[0]) {
        if (scores[curPos] < scores[curPos-1]) {
            rankAry[curRank] = scores[curPos]; //update the rank break point
            curRank++; //moved down in rank
        }
        curPos++; //move down the array
    }

    if (curPos == scores.Length) { //smallest score still bigger than Alice's first
        rankAry[curRank] = alice[0]; //pretend there was a virtual value at the end
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < alice.Length; ++i) {
        if (curRank == 1) { //if we're at the top, we're going to stay there
            res[i] = 1;
            continue;
        }

        //Non-degenerate cases
        while (alice[i] >= rankAry[curRank - 1]) {
            if (curRank == 1 || alice[i] < rankAry[curRank - 1]) {
                break;
            }

            curRank--;
        }
        res[i] = curRank;
    }

    return res;
}
```